# Node/Express app find onhashchange event handler

Tags: node.js, url, express

I'm working on a Node.js website, I've taken the work on for a charity and I confess I'm learning on the job.

The page in question starts with content rendered, but invisible.  When you click a button that redirects to a URL starting with a # ( which means it gets appended to the page ), no get occurs, but the content is revealed . The issue is, it needs to be filtered.  However, I cannot figure out what is triggering this.  The word 'hashchange' does not occur in the code base.  The window.onhashchange event is null.  Where would I look to try to track down the code that is doing this ?

Comment: OK, I've worked it out, it's using bootstrap tabs.  They are just all being shown when one gets clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content after the hash mark is called an [URL fragment](https://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/). URL fragments are not sent to the server and appending an URL fragment does not typically invoke a page fetch, so it makes sense that no get occurs.

URL fragments are commonly used to keep track of navigation state on the browser side. This is common with single page apps (SPA) that will only fetch the entire page from the server once, and handle the rest of navigation using javascript, pushState, and AJAX queries.

This is presumably what is happening when you navigate to different tabs. The client side javascript is appending URL fragment in order to push state onto the browser history without forcing an unnecessary page reload. Note that this code does not need to listen to the `onhashchange` event in order for this to work, which is why you don't see any mention of it in your code search.

Comment: Thanks - I did work this out, and I'm not sure why it took so long, I could just see a controller I was sure was doing what I was seeing, but in fact the whole thing is done with bootstrap tabs.  It's just not working.  2 days to find the problem, 10 minutes to fix it :)